# Files from folder to a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, filenames

I have tried to search the net for a solution but with no luck.

I have a folder containing some `.txt` files. I want to read the files to a dictionary so that each filename is a key and its content is the value.

Comment: Have you tried to write any code at all to start with? If so, could you supply it to see what you've done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below will be a good start for you to work with and improve.

```
import os

direc = os.getcwd() # Get current working directory
ext = '.txt' # Select your file delimiter

file_dict = {} # Create an empty dict

# Select only files with the ext extension
txt_files = [i for i in os.listdir(direc) if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ext]

# Iterate over your txt files
for f in txt_files:
    # Open them and assign them to file_dict
    with open(os.path.join(direc,f)) as file_object:
        file_dict[f] = file_object.read()

# Iterate over your dict and print the key/val pairs.
for i in file_dict:
    print i, file_dict[i]
```

You can remove the "os.getcwd()" if you wish to use another directory, just set direc = '/some/other/directory/'.

Comment: Thanks a lot and help with the file delimiter. I was trying to loop over the os.listdir but got an key error for a DS Store file.

Comment: By that do you mean that you were having problems with a DS Store file with the code above? The code is written so only files with a '.txt' extension should be added to the dictionary. If you were looping over os.listdir() later on and trying to use that for keys in the dictionary then yes it'll break on files that don't have a '.txt' extension. I'm not quite sure what your comment referred to (whether you were saying that you still had a problem or whether you were thanking me for solving your problem).

Comment: I was thanking you. It was my own code where, I was trying to loop over os.listdir() and got the Key Error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file named `tech.py`

```
import os
d={}
path="PathToFolderWhereFilesAreLocated"

filename="tech.py"
f=open(os.path.join(path,filename),"r")
value=f.read()
d[filename]=value
```

Now if you want to work with multiple files you can create a list of filenames and iteratively create a dictionary for more than one file.